# Best method of searching a string for a set of characters and replacing those characters with a link?

Tags: javascript

For example, on Reddit:

If your comment contains `r/foobar`, `r/foobar` gets replaced with a link to `reddit.com/r/foobar`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Whoever upvoted this please stand up and identify yourself. We need to revoke your SO account

Comment: Have you tried using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)? Please show your attempt.

Comment: @docyoda it’s important that you provide a good quality question. A minimum acceptable standard should contain code examples and context. For example, is the string you want to replace a substring in a Dom element, part of an array or inside an object.

Comment: @docyoda It has nothing to do with you directly, but rather with a fellow member having no idea what the upvote is to be used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `String.prototype.replace()` method with using Regular Expressions. Good documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

### Super Basic Example:

```
var inputString = 'Some text with a link to r/foobar on Reddit.';
var regEx = /(r\/foobar)/g;

console.log(inputString.replace(regEx, 'reddit.com/$&'));
// Expected results: 'Some text with a link to reddit.com/r/foobar on Reddit.'
```

Your original question says "replacing those characters with a link?". I don't think you meant an actual anchor-tag link (r/foobar), however, this same method could be used with some changes.

### More Complex Example:

Since the `string.replace()` method is just swapping a string for another string, it won't work alone to swap a string with an HTML element. If you use it with the addition of something like `element.innerHTML` it will work. Take the following example:

Assuming we have an html document containing a paragraph that looks like this:

```
<p class="my-class">Some text with a link to r/foobar, r/bar, and r/foo on Reddit.</p>
```

And some JS running on that page:

```
var p = document.querySelector('.my-class');
var regEx = /(r\/foobar|r\/bar)/g;

p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(regEx, '<a href="https://reddit.com/$&">$&</a>'); // This is going to wrap "r/foobar" & "r/bar" in an HTML anchor tag in the paragraph because it's combined with element.innerHTML
```

**Things to note:**

1. My `regEx` variable has the `g` global flag at the end, meaning it won't stop at one match, it keeps going.
2. In Regex you must escape a forward slash `/` with a preceding backslash `\`.
3. The Regex is using a capture group (inside the parentheses `()`).
4. The Regex is using a logical or (`|`) operator.
5. The replacement uses `$&` to call the capture group and stick it in the replacement (twice). You can call a full regex match with `$&` or individual captures with `$n` where `n` is equal to the captures order (`$1` is first capture `$2` is second...)

See the working [codepen demonstration](https://codepen.io/wdzajicek/pen/PooxKzZ)